# How to determine sample size for an unknown probability?

Tags: statistics

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge in statistics; I am not sure my title even makes sense.

Within my company, I have been entrusted to determine whether we have a biased promotion process. I need to measure the rate at which women are promoted and the rate at which men are promoted, and determine whether there is a systemic bias. I also need to measure the rates of being nominated for promotion.

I would like to determine how many promotion cycles (samples) I need in order to draw a statistically significant conclusion. This is where I do not know how to even set the problem up.

For simplicity, let's say there are 75 men and 25 women. Each cycle, each person is either nominated or not nominated. Of those that are nominated, each is either approved or declined.

I figure there are four probabilities I need to measure:

```
p_m_nom = chance a male is nominated
p_m_app = chance a male is approved
p_f_nom = chance a female is nominated
p_f_app = chance a female is approved
```

Ultimately I'd like to determine the number of samples needed to gain a 75% certainty that there is or is not a difference between the `p_f`'s and the corresponding `p_m`'s.

Please feel free to use great liberty in answering this - I'm not quite sure how to even frame the problem or what language to use. Thank you!

Comment: Please ask your company to hire a consultant who knows enough about statistics to be able to produce a satisfactory protocol. If you can't do it yourself, you have no business being in charge of the project, and no business asking for free help when your company could be supporting some deserving scientist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a test of binomial proportions being the same -- searching "binomial proportions test" will give lots of hits (eg https://www.statsdirect.com/help/proportions/single.htm).

I'll comment that you can never actually hope to be 75% certain there's a difference or not between the $p_f$ and the $p_m$: if the two are very different from each other, you won't need many samples to tell them apart, if they're different but very close, you'll need very many samples (and you can never have enough samples to rule out the latter). What you can do is have a threshold of closeness you want to test for -- eg., is the difference at most 0.01? -- and calculate a sample size for that. The rule of thumb, from a normal approximation, is that you need $n$ samples to estimate a binomial parameter to within $1.15/(4\sqrt{n})$ (the $1.15$ comes from $P(|Z|>1.15)\approx0.75$ for $Z\sim N(0,1)$). Sharper regions (calculated directly for binomials) exist too, eg see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval, but the normal approximation, while a bit crude, is probably good enough for your purposes.